# Oracle declare an array and assign ids to this array with for loop and finally show up the ids in rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to write a query which have an array declare and get all agent_id from a select query to this array with a loop and finally show up the ids in rows with another loop here is below the query, but I can not do the loop

Comment: Your english makes it a little difficult to understand.  Could you please add a sample of the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples.

The first one fetches data into your own array and displays the result:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number) as
  2    type my_type is record (ename    emp.ename%type,
  3                            job      emp.job%type,
  4                            sal      emp.sal%type);
  5    type my_type_t is table of my_type;
  6    l_data my_type_t;
  7  begin
  8    select e.ename,
  9           e.job,
 10           e.sal
 11    bulk collect into l_data
 12    from emp e
 13    where e.deptno = par_deptno;
 14
 15    for i in 1 .. l_data.count loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line(l_data(i).ename ||' - '|| l_data(i).job ||
 17                           to_char(l_data(i).sal, '$999G990D00'));
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec p_test(10);
CLARK - MANAGER   $2.450,00
KING - PRESIDENT   $5.000,00
MILLER - CLERK   $1.300,00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Another one uses ref cursor:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test_2
  2    (par_deptno in number, par_rc out sys_refcursor)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    open par_rc for
  6      select e.ename,
  7           e.job,
  8           e.sal
  9      from emp e
 10      where e.deptno = par_deptno;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var l_rc refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec p_test_2(10, :l_rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :l_rc;

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
CLARK      MANAGER         2450
KING       PRESIDENT       5000
MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL>
```

Comment: can you do it with my query please

Comment: I could, but - why would I? I told you how to do it. What's the problem in writing it yourself? I don't have your tables, I can't even test it. If you posted CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, I might.

Comment: You must be kidding. Code in your question uses number of columns from `cardprintlog_user` table. My example uses Scott's sample schema (which you are not satisfied with). Then you posted SQL Fiddle with some columns that aren't related to `cardprintlog_user` table (`agents_id, name, time` columns - they don't exist in the question). So what difference would it make if I rewrite my code to SQL Fiddle table? You can't apply it to your original question anyway.